# Using Python 3 to fill in text boxes on websites, and clicking button to download

Tags: python, python-3.x, web-scraping, python-requests

I want to download YouTube videos with Python. I found a website (https://www.youtubeinmp4.com/) which can download YouTube videos in mp4 format.

I am using **Python 3**, BeautifulSoup and requests to get the videos URL from YouTube and I have no idea how can I download it from the website.

Is there any way to fill in the text box with the YouTube video URL and then click the "Download MP4" button?

Answer (score 1):

Don't do it like that. You better use [Youtube-dl](https://rg3.github.io/youtube-dl/)

You can write a python script to call youtube-dl, because it's a Command line program.

If you still wanna use python to fill out fields, take a loot on [selenium](http://www.seleniumhq.org/)

You can locate and use Elements on html pages.

Comment: Youtube-dl is written in Python, btw, it can be embedded as raw source to any Python app. With some skill applied, of course.